# Three JS Geometry not rendering in scene?

Tags: three.js

I'm a complete beginner with `three.js` and am just trying to get to grips with creating a basic scene. I have copied and pasted code from a tutorial into `VSCode` and executed it through the live server extension.

This is the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Three.js Basic Scene</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <script src="three.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
        var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        renderer.setClearColor(0xDDDDDD, 1);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT);
        camera.position.z = 50;
        scene.add(camera);

        var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 10);
        var basicMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0095DD });
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, basicMaterial);
        scene.add(cube);
        cube.rotation.set(0.4, 0.2, 0);

        function render() {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        render();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The intended output is a blue cube on the screen with a white background, however all i am getting is a completely white screen. Any ideas why this is happening when the code is completely copied and pasted?

Comment: Make sure `three.min.js` can be actually loaded by the app. Maybe there is a 404 HTTP error because the file is located in a different directory.

Comment: Check your console (F12) for any error messages. That's the first place to start for things like this. If you don't understand what the error message is saying, post it here (edit your question, don't put it in a comment) and maybe someone can help sort it out.

Comment: Hi Jim, took your advice and checked the console. There was some errors about not being able to import three.js outside of a module, all sorted now though thanks for the help :)